# Bourbon family without Ruby

Tags: ruby, gulp, bower, bourbon, neat

I'm currently trying to make my company use Bourbon/Neat/Bitters/Refills, the Toughtbot front-end stack often refered as the Bourbon family.

But while we use Ruby on most of our projects, we code static websites from time to time. On that kind of project, the scaffolding speed of Bitters could be very useful.

Thoughtbot released Bower packages for Bourbon and Neat, not for Bitters and Refills. Combined with Gulp for Sass pre-processing, Bower is perfect for small projects.

I can't find a reasonably reliable way to use Bitters and Refills for static websites. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don’t publish Bitters or Refills to Bower because we expect authors to change the code they come with. They are there are get you started.

For Bitters, I recommend using the gem, which comes with a CLI. We publish installation instructions on our GitHub: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters#installation

For Refills, you can also use the gem, or simply copy-paste from the website: https://github.com/thoughtbot/refills#installation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we'll digg into it.